# create soap request using jquery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

I want create soap request of specific function.my code as follow which is not calling that function , this return the whole wsdl xml file as a response. plz check code if i made any mistake...

```
var soapMessage='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
                soapMessage+='<SOAP-ENV:Envelope';
                    soapMessage+=' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"';
                    soapMessage+=' xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"';
                    soapMessage+=' xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"';
                    soapMessage+=' xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"';
                    soapMessage+=' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"';
                    soapMessage+='>\n';
                soapMessage+='<SOAP-ENV:Body>\n';
                soapMessage+='<ns1:userdetail xmlns:ns1="urn:xmds" SOAP-ENC:root="1">\n';
                    soapMessage+='<username xsi:type="xsd:string">1</username>\n';
                    soapMessage+='<gender xsi:type="xsd:string">1</gender>\n';
                soapMessage+='</ns1:userdetail>\n';
            soapMessage+='</SOAP-ENV:Body>\n';
            soapMessage+='</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';


    $.ajax({
                       url: "http://myIP/server/xmds.php?wsdl",
                       type: "POST",
                      beforeSend: function (xhr){
                       //xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:xmds#RestoreDisplayIfAny");
                       //xhr.setRequestHeader("host", "http://MYIP/server/");
                       //xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPTarget","http://MYIP/server/xmds.php?wsdl");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://MYIP/server/");
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                       alert("in before send");
                       },

                      // crossDomain: true,
                       dataType: "xml",
                       data: soapMessage,
                       complete: endSaveProduct,
                       contentLength:599,
                       contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
                       }).done(function () {alert("calling Authenticate");})
                .fail( function() {alert("fail");});
});
```

Comment: Is this request being made inside the same domain? Remember AJAX cannot make cross-domain requests.

Comment: yes the request is made in same domain. issue is it's not calling that function (userdetail). is the soap request structure is correct??